# Portainer login via Keycloak redirects to the same page

Tags: cloud, keycloak, keycloak-services, portainer, keycloak-connect

I'm in charge of doing the tests and then implementing keycloak at work, I followed all the steps from installation to configuration, I wanted to know where I was going wrong because when I log in via keycloak on my portainer page, instead of being sent to the home page is directed to the same login page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuzqE.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBKg6.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1teA.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAGju.jpg) [Login to portainer and where it is redirected again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je0ua.jpg) [Login to Portainer with keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QCmU.jpg)

I tried following several videos but it always ends up in the same situation.